# Common problem with CSS margin

Tags: css, html, margin

I do not know how common this problem is for other users, but for me, it's pretty common and I have no real idea why it is happening.

But let me explain the symptoms. :)

When ever I do a layout using css and divs I many times end up with some place where margin just stops working as it should. It could be that it adds space to the left and right but usually not top and down.

Other times a margin on top of a div results in an unwanted space further down on the page.

Anyone with experience of this problem? And what am I probably doing wrong?

All divs are of course properly closed, so it isn't that obvious. And I know, I know, it's super hard to answer width no real example. I'm just throwing out a rope gere and hoping for a savior. Thanks!

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer this question if you could provide a specific example (via JSFiddle, for example).

Comment: It will be helpful if u paste some code.

Comment: I know, I know.. but problem is that it usually happens when I have a lot going on, loads of code. If i knew the precise parts of code where it happened I would probably figure out what is wrong.

Comment: My hope is that someone recognize the problem and say: "Hey, you probably added margin on a floating div, but forgot to clear it and that is probably why your margins are screwed up" :)

Comment: i think your css style can be overridden by previouse applied css style so thats why this problem is arrived. check out that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with `float` and `margin` together. margin will not apply for example if you have a `div` with `float:right` and another div without float after it ! no margin between these two elements will be applied. unless you set a float for second element too !

but remember in these situations, `margin` applied for contents of both elements. not for borders. content will align correctly but borders not!

this is a common problem that we can call it as a BROWSER BUG!

If you have eny specific problem let us to know.

Comment: I am not sure if this is exactly the problem, always, but it is an good answer, Probably the best one I can get to this wage question.

Answer (score 0):

if u can post some code..it will be helpful.  see these sites and try to see where ur going wrong..
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp